# Diferença entre props e propsData

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

No `Vue.js` temos como inserir dados em componentes por meio de `props`  da seguinte forma.

```
const hello = {
  template: '<div>{{ message }}',
  props: ['message']
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Pt Stackoverflow',
  },
  components: {
    hello,
  }
});
```

Lendo a documentação mais a fundo me deparei com `propsData` que de acordo com a documentação:

> Passa props a uma instância durante a sua criação. A intenção disso é
>   primariamente tornar testes unitários mais fáceis.

Sou novo no `Vue.js` então não sou expert em testes de componentes, onde de acordo com o texto acima seria um exemplo de caso de uso dessa estratégia.

Alguém poderia me explicar de forma que eu entenda a diferença entre as duas e se possível um exemplo do uso de `propsData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ambos são a mesma coisa mas em fazes diferentes da vida do componente.

Quando defines o componente ele precisa de ter algumas das propriedades estruturais de um componente Vue, como `props`, `data`, `methods`, etc... ferramentas que a API do Vue disponibiliza. Neste caso as `props` são uma definição e aí podes definir se a prop é obrigatória (`required: true`) que tipo é e podes até ter uma função validatória ou um valor por defeito caso a prop não tenha valor próprio.

Quando chega a altura de usar esse componente, ou seja de criar uma instância, essas props que declaraste antes precisam de ter os valores que o componente vai consumir. Aí entram as `propsData`. Os valores nesse objeto vão ser passados à instância e ser usados como valores.

O teu exemplo com propsData seria assim:

```js
const hello = {
  template: '<div>{{ message }}</div>',
  props: ['message']
};

// montando um componente dentro do template de outro (o caso mais habitual)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Pt Stackoverflow',
  },
  components: {
    hello,
  }
});

// criando o elemento fora do template
new Vue({
  ...hello,
  propsData: {
    message: 'Pt Stackoverflow',
  }
}).$mount(document.getElementById('hello2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <hello message="Olá"></hello>
</div>

<span id="hello2"></span>
```

Comment: Onde eu defino o `propsData` no próprio componente ou no componente pai?

Comment: Quais as `fases` que cada um é usado?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizS o `propsData` é usado para criar o componente que tem `props` defenido. Podes criar um componente com uma função, não precisa de ser um componente pai. Não têm "fases", o `propsData` é o objeto que vai ser usado pelo novo componente nas suas `props`.

Comment: Obrigado entendi agora.

Comment: Minha última dúvida na documentação é dito que ele é usado primariamente em testes e somente durante a fase de criação da instância, é uma forma de injetar dados para realizar testes? E depois da criação `props` tem prioridade sobre `propsData`?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizS `propsData` e `props` é a mesma coisa. Quando o componente é iniciado consome as `propsData` que o objeto passado ao contrutor recebe e a instância disponibiliza esse objeto nas `props`.